# Uninstall Nagios Core on AWS EC2 instance

Tags: linux

I have installed Nagios Core using this 
[guide](https://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/93152-installing-nagios-core-on-amazon-linux-instance) and would like to uninstall it now. I can't seem to find any installation guide online. I am new in this area. Can anybody help?

Comment: you are using cloud, better to create another instance

Answer (score 1):

Follow the below steps and you can remove it from your machine

You just do the steps in reverse(ish) order:

Stop the Nagios daemon

Remove the web conf, if you installed it

Remove the user and group that you added for Nagios

Remove the init script

Remove /usr/local/nagios directory

---Let me know if you have any trouble .

you can grep these files on machine

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that, you followed that guide you have a Centos or Red Hat system? To check this, run the following: `cat /etc/redhat-release`

Seeing as you installed it from sources, you can uninstall the application with `make uninstall`, but that's only if the developer created the option to uninstall the application in this manner. And if that doesn't work, unfortunately you'll have to find the step that `make` took to install the application (log files) and reverse all these steps.